# mysql count(*) in joins with one-to-many table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to perform a COUNT on a quite a big query, where one of the joined tables has a one-to-many relationship. This is throwing off my result as all data is being multiplied by the number of times an item is repeated in the 'many' side of the one-to-many table.

This is a shortened version of the query showing only the relevant portion to highlight the issue:

```
SELECT COUNT(trimtype) FROM versiontrim 
INNER JOIN trims USING (trim_id) 
INNER JOIN prices USING(version_id) 
INNER JOIN m_versions USING(version_id)
WHERE trimtype IN('sec', 'help') AND price BETWEEN 200001 AND 210000 
GROUP BY version_id
```

All tables are quite straighforward except m_versions that has the one-to-many relationship and looks like this:

```
version_id       serv_id

  1                 1
  1                 2
  1                 3
  1                 4
  1                 5
  .... and so on
```

The expected result of the query is :

```
version_id  COUNT(trimtype)     
44          9
54          7
69          9
214         10
216         6
282         1
290         10
```

Instead I am getting this,ie, all counts multiplied by 5 which is the number of times version_id is repeated in the m_versions table:

```
version_id  COUNT(trimtype)     
44         45
54          35
69          45
214         50
216         30
282         5
290         50
```

How to avoid this behavior?
Thanks

Comment: What if you replace with `COUNT(DISTINCT trimtype)` ?

Comment: if you replace it with `COUNT(DISTINCT trimtype)`, the maximum value will be `2` because you are filtering only for `2` values in the `where` clause. `WHERE trimtype IN ('sec', 'help')....`

Comment: JW is right. I tried DISTINCT both for trimtype and then for version_id but did not get what I am looking for.

Comment: Yes, it depends on which table the `trimtype` belongs and what the relationships between the various tables are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It matches to multiple records on table `m_version` that is why you are getting invalid result. Try wrapping it a subquery,

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT version_id FROM m_versions) m USING(version_id)
```

**UPDATE**

So the full query will look like this,

```
SELECT version_id, COUNT(trimtype) 
FROM   versiontrim 
       INNER JOIN trims USING (trim_id) 
       INNER JOIN prices USING(version_id) 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT version_id FROM m_versions) m USING(version_id)
WHERE  trimtype IN('sec', 'help') AND price BETWEEN 200001 AND 210000 
GROUP  BY version_id
```

Comment: Fantastic JW, that does it! Always learning new things. I did not know at all that you could use a subquery within a JOIN. Thanks a lot!